# Placing definition of enum class, used as template parameter for a template class, inside the template class

Tags: c++, templates, enum-class

I like to define my enum's that belong to a certain class inside that class. That makes it clear they belong together and helps against namespace pollution:

```
class Bar
{
public:

    enum class Foo
    {
        something,
        somethingElse
    };

    Bar(Foo foo);

    //etc...
};
```

Purely out of curiosity I'd like to know if one can do the same for a enum class that is used as template parameter for the class it's defined in:

```
template <Bar::Foo foo>
class Bar
{
public:

    enum class Foo
    {
        something,
        somethingElse
    };
};
```

Obviously this won't compile because `Bar` has not been declared yet at the moment we try to use `Bar::Foo` as a template parameter type. I'd like to see if someone can come up with some creative workaround.

Comment: You cannot forward declare a nested type I fear. So no, not possible.

Comment: You could make the c'tor private and provide a public/friend factory function to only instance with specific template args.